# Kwallet system disabled in Kubuntu 15.10 but Kopete still uses it

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, kwallet, kopete

I have disabled the Kwallet system

[image]

But when I try to use Kopete messenger, it asks for a Kwallet password

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked  (after disabling the service as seen in the image) was to remove

```
~/.config/kwalletrc
~/.kde4/share/apps/kwallet/* 
~/.kde4/share/config/kwalletrc
```

(as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29945946/4098390))